# Regular expression with skipping a few words

Tags: python, html, regex

I am struggling to just get the text in between the quotes in the 'alt' tag. I have been trying regular expressions like [!?border="0"] to skip over it but still won't work.

I have tried `\s(border="0")\s(alt=").*?"` but it highlights over the 'border' tag

Here's the text that i'm trying to extract from using regex

```
<img src="http://www.ebgames.com.au/0141/169/5.png"alt="Far Cry 3" title=" Far Cry 3 " class="photo"/>            </a>
```

I am just trying to extract the text in between the quotes of the alt tag. Extracting the title would probably be better if possible.
Please help, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
border=\"0\" alt=\"(.*?)\"
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1kbiBv/1/

You could also implement Positive Look-ahead, and Positive Look-behind to catch only what is between quotes:

```
(?<=border=\"0\" alt=\").*?(?=\")
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1kbiBv/2/

Comment: Thanks for your help. This one was simple and worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

There is better way to extract html element and attribute with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
div_test='<img src="http://rcdn-1.fishpond.com.au/0141/169/297/319967448/5.jpeg" border="0" alt="The Durrells: Series 2" title=" The Durrells: Series 2 " class="photo"/> '
soup = BeautifulSoup(div_test, "lxml")
result = soup.find("img").get('alt')
result
```

Output:

```
'The Durrells: Series 2'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `lambda` in order to extract your tags from your current input.

You can try this code:

```
import re

a = '''<img src="http://rcdn-1.fishpond.com.au/0141/169/297/319967448/5.jpeg" border="0" alt="The Durrells: Series 2" title=" The Durrells: Series 2 " class="photo"/>            </a>
'''

find_tag = lambda x: r'{0}="(.*?)"'.format(x)
# Same as doing:
# regex = re.compile(find_tag('border="0" alt'))
regex = re.compile(find_tag("alt"))
text = re.findall(regex, a)
print(text)
```

Output:

```
['The Durrells: Series 2']
```

Also, this code will work with the other tags as well, for example:

```
regex = re.compile(find_tag("src"))
# Same as doing:
# regex = re.compile(find_tag('<img src'))
text = re.findall(regex, a)
print(text)
```

Output:

```
['http://rcdn-1.fishpond.com.au/0141/169/297/319967448/5.jpeg']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `re.search` with a simple regex works.

```
import re
s = '<img src="himg src="http://www.ebgames.com.au/0141/169/5.png" border="0" alt="Far Cry 3" title=" Far Cry 3 " class="photo"/>            </a>'
pat = 'alt="([^"]*)".* title="([^"]*)".*"'
a = re.search(pat, s)
print(a[1]) # content in the alt tag : "Far Cry 3"
print(a[2]) # content in the alt title : "Far Cry 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code finds what you need, using this pattern: `'alt=".*?"'`.

```
 import re

 w ='<img src="http://rcdn-1.fishpond.com.au/0141/169/297/319967448/5.jpeg" border="0" alt="The 
 Durrells: Series 2" title=" The Durrells: Series 2 " class="photo"/>   </a>'

 pattern = 'alt=".*?"'
 m = re.findall(pattern, w)
 print(m)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!